# There is an error in : field Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: json, angular, api, symfony

This is screenshot of postman which return a json array [postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6znjp.jpg).
How can i solve?

**userservice.ts**

```
addUser(user: User) {
const  headers = new Headers();

headers.append('content-type', 'application/json');
headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.authenticationService.token);
return this.http.post(this.uri, JSON.stringify(user), {headers : headers})
.map(res => res.json());
}
```

in network devtools i had this [screenshot of network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMT0W.jpg)
       add-user.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-user',
  templateUrl: './add-user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-user.component.css']
})
export class AddUserComponent implements OnInit {

  username: string ;
  email: string;
  errors= [];
  constructor(private _userService: UserService , private router: Router) { }

  addUser(username, email) {

    let user: any;
    user = {username: username, email: email};
    this._userService.addUser(user).subscribe(
      result => this.router.navigate(['/users']),
      err => this.errors.push(err)

    );
  }
 ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**usercontroller**

```
 * @param Request $request
     * @param Validate $validate
     * @return JsonResponse
     * @Route("/api/users",name="create_user")
     * @Method({"POST"})
     */
    public function createUser(Request $request,Validate $validate)
    {
        $data=$request->getContent();
        $user=$this->get('jms_serializer')->deserialize($data,'AppBundle\Entity\User','json');
        $reponse=$validate->validateRequest($user);
        if (!empty($reponse)){
            return new JsonResponse($reponse, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();
        $response=array(
            'code'=>0,
            'message'=>'Post created!',
            'errors'=>null,
            'result'=>null
        );
        return new JsonResponse($response,Response::HTTP_CREATED);
    }
```

Comment: add screenshot of network response also .

Comment: "how can i solve"  - what exactly you mean by "solve"?

Comment: @Sachin  this is the screnshot of  network response  https://prnt.sc/i15x2v

Comment: @rudolf_franek i mean what's my  problem

Comment: @enginer this is not the network response I am expecting , thats the whole index file I guess.

Comment: @Sachin the network response that mean's  the index file?

Comment: by response I meant the json response you are getting from your web services. But you response contains only html code.

Comment: i think that's mean i had probleme in my backend not frontend @Sachin

Comment: Yeah the response from backend is the problem .

Comment: even though I received a correct json in postman ? @Sachin

Comment: you didn't posted that response ?

Comment: @Sachin i posted in my post and now this my screenshot http://prntscr.com/i3upqf

Comment: yeah , the response is already in json format . No need for conversion right?

Comment: Like I said just remove the `map` and `res.json()` inside it.

Comment: @Sachin even though in list users i remove  `the map `  and `res.json() ` => https://prnt.sc/i1belb ?

Comment: did the error still exist ? There is no need for the `map` function right? Remove it then.

Comment: the error didn't exist just it didn't display in database and list users i think i had error  in backend createUser.so thanks @Sachin for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your code**

```
return this.http.post(this.uri, JSON.stringify(user), {headers : headers})
.map(res => res.json());
```

**remove the map function from this**

you are trying to convert neither an object nor an array to json and that is the problem.

**or**

```
 return this.http.post(this.uri, JSON.stringify(user), {headers : headers})
    .map(res => console.log(res));
```

**check using above code and paste your console value**

Comment: sreenshot of userservice for list http://prntscr.com/i1belb  and screeshot for usercomponents.ts http://prntscr.com/i1bfdk i think i make i had something wrong @sachin

Comment: i changed my code, it didn't display in list users and in the database too is not adding screenshot : http://prntscr.com/i1bk1u   what 's the problem do you think.

Comment: @enginer you are getting the error in the front end or backend?